# Google closure compiler for aem 6.1

Tags: gcc, aem

Can anybody say how to use Google Closure Compiler(gcc) with AEM 6.1. I am running into a problem with default AEM 6.1 minification (i.e., YUI compiler).

Regards,
Sree.

Answer (score 0):

To use gcc, set the `jsProcessor` property on the clientlib (i.e., if you have a clientlib in `/apps/site/clientlibs/mylib`, edit `/apps/site/clientlibs/mylib/.content.xml`) to `[default:gcc,min:gcc]`.

This will use gcc both in the minified version and the non-minified version of the clientlib. You can also use `default:none,min:gcc` to only apply gcc in the minified version.

Additionally, you can pass gcc options by separating them with `;`, e.g.: `default:gcc;languageIn=ECMASCRIPT_2019;compilationLevel=whitespace;languageOut=ECMASCRIPT_2019`.